# EPIC created in TFS doesn't appear in PBI / sprints

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

I'm using TFS (web) and using the scrum template. On the main page/dashboard, under Work->Create New->Epic. I have created an Epic. This epic is associated to Sprint 5 in my project. I've also created sub story associated with that epic. However, I'm unable to see that story, or the epic under sprint 5.

When I query the epic, TFS displays it, so I know for sure that exists. But it doesn't list in Sprint.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Typically Epics don't belong to Sprints, they are higher level.  When you are in the sprint planning screen or the sprint taskboard view, it will show requirements (ie user stories, use cases, pbi's, bugs, defects) and tasks.

You can always create a WI query to return all PBI's and Epics assigned to a Sprint if you want.

Comment: Thank you Dylan, that helps. 1) Apart from as a Query result, is there any option available in TFS to see the Epics? (through web interface). 2) Also would Epics have PBI items [I'm confused as I dont see an option to add user stories under epics. So Im guessing it would have PBI's]. Correct me if Im wrong. If I'm correct, then would they be visible in the respective sprints?

Comment: So when you say "visible in the sprint" that wording is confusing.  Everything that is assigned to the sprint is "in the sprint".  Then there are multiple different views in the web interface to see different subsets of data.  Queries are the main way to access WI data.  Then there are a few backlog screens that are specifically tailored for certain experiences (backlog/portfolio grooming which shows epics, sprint planning, sprint taskboards which don't, etc).